# how to iterate through function[i]()?

Tags: c++, function, iterator

Thanks for reading. I am new to programming, and I am trying to write a function that will iterate through all the i values. For example, it may be function3() and then iterates to a random function12(). This is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    trigFunction();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void trigFunction()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Welcome to Haris's Unit Circle Fun House!\n";
    srand(time(NULL));
    i = rand()%15;
    for (int x = 1; x < 15; x++)
    {
        functioni(); //This is obviously wrong. Is there way to do this correctly?
        i = rand() % 15;
    }

}
```

functioni() I have defined below the text, for example:

```
void function3()
{
    cout << "What is 5pi/3 in degrees?\n";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 300)
    {
        cout << "Correct answer!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong Answer!\n";
    }
}
void function4()
{
    cout << "What is 3pi/2 in degrees?\n";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 270)
    {
        cout << "Correct answer!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong Answer!\n";
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Edit: Is there a way to implement arrays into a function structure? Like functioni?

Comment: Upvoted to cancel out the downvote. This isn't a bad question, just misphrased somewhat.

Comment: @Xenopathic Upvotes are not to balance out downvotes. I've retracted mine now. Is the result really what you intended??

Comment: While there is an obvious answer to your question, I'm reluctant to give it, because there's probably a much better way to solve your *actual* problem.

Comment: @user3088723 you cannot generate function names using variables in C++! The closest thing you might get is a vector of function pointers to be called for particular values of `i`. But I doubt this will really solve what you want to get. In short that smells ...

Comment: I have only taken one programming course. As I progress through my major, I am sure I will learn better methods. But for now with the little content that I have covered and can use, I would like to solve this using it.

Comment: @KerrekSB It looks to me like the goal is to call a random one of these functions, and the obvious answer to the question is a good way of achieving that, IMO. Did you have another goal in mind, or do you disagree with what I posted as an answer?

Comment: hvd, you are right. I want to be asked random questions. I will try to see if your solution works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this question deserves my upvote anyway, since the question title is particularly attractive to new C++ users who might be looking for function pointers.

Comment: @Xenopathic Alright, everything fine then ;) ...

Comment: @hvd: It's hard to disagree, since there's no logical fault with the answers. I would however question their pedagogical value, since the user's problem would be solved far more elegantly and productively with a different approach (say a container of question-answer pairs).

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point, I hadn't noticed how extremely similar the two functions were. It wouldn't work if any question doesn't have a fixed question and answer text, but they very well all might.

Comment: @hvd: (For example, a container can be iterated and populated dynamically; with the function pointers, you have to keep the pointers and the actual functions in sync manually.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to remember is that at runtime, function names don't really exist any longer. At least, not in a form that you can reliably and portably use to look up the function.

You'll have to map the names (or, in this case, just numbers) to the functions somehow. A simple way to do this is to use an array.

```
typedef void (*pfun)();
pfun functions[] = { function0, function1, function2, function3, function4 };
```

You can then call `functions[i]();` Note that array indices start at 0, and that things will break badly if `i` gets an incorrect value.

Comment: Technically right, yes. But I believe the OP asks for a XY Problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't. The question suggests that the goal is to call a random one of fifteen functions, and I would use an array for that, exactly what I have here.

Comment: Wow, this actually works! I will read about pointers to fully understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that a jump into any function (the low-level instruction sent to the processor) has to be known at compile time. Since your iteration values may change based on variables not known at compile time, this doesn't work. However, there is a way to get around this - using function objects.

A function object stores the jump required to get to a function, however it acts like a normal variable that can be copied around, and more importantly, stored in an index-based array. This lets you store function objects in an array, so that `func_array[3]` is a function object pointing to `function3`.

```
#include <functional>

int myfunc(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(int, int)> func = myfunc;
    int c = func(6, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

That is a crude example, but it should help you make an array with function objects pointing to all your functions.

Just to point out, this is an example that uses C++11, while hvd's answer is the C++03 approach.